# empty folder in container when docker run -v in

Tags: docker

I am using Docker version 18.09.2 on windows 10.
I want to mount a folder into linux container using command

```
docker run -it -v C:\work:/mnt/data/work ubuntu bash
```

when in new console I check the container by using command

```
 docker inspect new_Created_Container_Name
```

This is the result :

```
 "Mounts": [
                {
                    "Type": "bind",
                    "Source": "/host_mnt/c/work",
                    "Destination": "/mnt/data/work",
                    "Mode": "",
                    "RW": true,
                    "Propagation": "rprivate"
                }
```

I believe that changing somehow the propagation value from rprivate to shared would solve the problem.
Is there easy way to achieve that ??

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Docker tries to mkdir the folder that I mount](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50817985/596285)

Comment: Reset credentials did not change the type of Propagation but I can see all files from my host machine in the bash container

Answer (score 0):

Docker runs inside of an embedded VM in windows. From the host you need to share the drive to the VM for the host volumes to work inside of docker. There is a setting for this in the Docker preferences, and if you change your password, you may need to reconfigure this sharing.

[image: Docker for Windows sharing]

Comment: I have shaded the driver C - I could paste the same picture from my PC

Comment: And the password? Have you tried clicking the "reset credentials" link?

Comment: Yes this was the solution : Settings->Shared Drivers->Reset credentials and check again the driver C