# AWS ECS task container

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I have this error in unique container on aws ecs task:

```
Error response from daemon: failed to mkdir /var/lib/docker/volumes/ecs-mrthink-task-5-mrthink-volume-c8ffaae4eaf6c9e7bb01/_data/staticfiles/admin/js/vendor/xregexp: mkdir /var/lib/docker/volumes/ecs-mrthink-task-5-mrthink-volu
```

Anybody know how to solve it ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There seems to be something missing at the end of the error message - can you check again? Is it a container with the EC2 launch type? Can you check on the node if there are sufficient Inodes and storage space available?

Comment: There could be many possibilities here [Docker tries to mkdir the folder that I mount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50817985/docker-tries-to-mkdir-the-folder-that-i-mount)  and make sure the permissions are correct.