# Receive mkdir error while trying docker-compose up

Tags: docker-compose

I get the following error while trying to compose-up a project.

```
ERROR: for backend  Cannot start service backend: error while creating mount source path '/private/var/folders': mkdir /private: file exists Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Can you please advise?

```
(...)
 backend:
    build:
      context: backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: python /app/backend/app/main.py
    ports:
      - 8888:8888
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/app/backend
      - ./.docker/.ipython:/root/.ipython:cached
      - /private/var/folders:/var/folders
    environment:
      PYTHONPATH: .
      MOSEY_ENV: "dev"
    depends_on:
      - "postgres"

(...)
```

Thank you,

Comment: Please add your docker compose configuration, are you using volumes? What container is this error coming from?

Comment: added; i use volume

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker tries to mkdir the folder that I mount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50817985/docker-tries-to-mkdir-the-folder-that-i-mount)

Comment: Do you mean restarting and building back: no.

Answer (score 0):

From your configuration with volumes and the error your are receiving, it seems to me that you have a file' at `/private` (global path on your computer, not your volume) which is causing the command to return an error.
The second option is that you are using OSX and the `/private` directory is restricted to the root user. You may have to run the command as sudo.