Failed to prevent docker from trying to mkdir the symlink that I mount
One case of Docker tries to mkdir the folder that I mount is that, I'm using symlink for that folder on my host (ref https://stackoverflow.com/a/65197779/2125837):
mkdir /tmp/aaa

$ ln -vsf aaa /tmp/aab
'/tmp/aab' -> 'aaa'

$ docker run --rm -it -v /tmp/aab:/new ubuntu echo "Hello"
docker: Error response from daemon: error while creating mount source path '/tmp/aab': mkdir /tmp/aab: file exists.


Are there any easier fix for it, other than using the heavy handed bind-mounting, so that I can use the symlink on my host as the source of docker volume?

Can you use readlink -f to get the absolute path for the bind mount source?

Use --mount, see docker documentation.

@DavidMaze, the reason I use symlink is to avoid the bind mount source being changing all the time. Think of I'm running docker in remote screen as a long lasting session while my SSH_AUTH_SOCK is changing all the time whenever I login.

@KamilCuk, would you be able to get my above example working with --mount? I'm getting docker: Error response from daemon: invalid mount config for type "bind": stat /tmp/aab: permission denied.

I confirm, I can reproduce stat /tmp/aab: permission denied. In contrast, docker run --rm -ti --mount type=bind,source="$(readlink -f /tmp/aab)",destination=/new alpine ls -la /new is ok.

If the location of the host directory changes, you need to recreate the bind mount, which in Docker means you need to recreate the container.  That's true of mounts in general and not specific to Docker.  (You can try without Docker running sudo mount --bind.)

Ok,  KamilCuk / David, I guess your answers conclude it. Thanks!
