# How to output progress of rsync by running it through a script in docker-compose?

Tags: bash, docker

I'm running rsync through a script, but I'm not getting the progress bar. It works fine when I run it directly, but when I run the script, I only get the echoes.

In my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
command: /home/node/build-dir/command.sh
tty    : true # Show output with syntax highlighting support.
```

```sh
#!/bin/ash

# First check if the directory is empty, as it is when it is mounted for the first time.
if [ -z "$(ls -A /home/node/work-dir/node_modules)" ]
  then
    echo 'Beginning to copy node_modules folder...'
    # Recursively copy all files of build directory to that of the working directory.
     rsync -ah --info=progress2 /home/node/build-dir/node_modules /home/node/work-dir/node_modules
    echo 'Finished copying node_modules folder...'
  else
    echo 'The folder "node_modules" already exists; skipping copying.'
fi

# Run npm start command to start development.
exec npm start
```

I want it to show the progress and then stop when it finishes, finishing the script run. I want it to be as if when I run it directly through the shell using `docker exec -it my_app ash` and then running the following:

```sh
rsync -ah --info=progress2 /home/node/build-dir/node_modules /home/node/work-dir/node_modules
```

So far, I get nothing, as in it acts the same as cp. I get the two echos "Beginning to copy..." and "Finished copying..." and that's it. Where's the progress?

- I tried to run the command through the shell on my host with test files and it worked.
- I tried to run the script through the shell on my host with test files and it worked.
- I tried to run the command through the shell from within the container and it worked.
- I tried to run the script through the shell from within the container and it worked.

My only assumption is that I've done something wrong with my `docker-compose.yml` file.

Comment: Docker images are supposed to be self-contained.  `RUN yarn install` in your Dockerfile so that the library tree is built into the image, and you won't need to run this `rsync` command at startup time.

Comment: @DavidMaze I'm trying to persist the `node_modules` in the container and mount it into a volume to appear on my host so I can integrate the functionalities of my IDE. Solution is taken from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43728476/1934402 I just need to see the progress through rsync.

Comment: You don't want Docker for that.  Just install and run Node locally, and use that for day-to-day development.  (With OS and library inconsistencies it's often hard to share `node_modules` trees anyways.)

Comment: So `rsync --progress`?

Comment: @KamilCuk That shows the progress per file. I want the overall progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using `docker-compose up...` while I was supposed to use `docker-compose run...`.

Source for finding my answer: [Interactive shell using Docker Compose](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36249744/1934402).